# Error : possible unintended reference comparison to get a value comparison cast the right hand

Tags: c#

I have the following code which gives a warning "possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the right hand side to type `string`":

```
// oControl is of type Control
if ((ocontrol.Name == oDataRowView["ConName"].ToString()))
{
   //Do stuff   
}
else
{
   //Do other Stuff
}
```

I've tried to fix it using each of the following but I still get a warning

```
if ((ocontrol.Name == Convert.ToString(oDataRowView["ConName"])))
{
   //Do stuff   
}
else
{
   //Do other Stuff
}  
if ((ocontrol.Name == (string)oDataRowView["ConName"]))
{
   //Do stuff   
}
else    
{
   //Do other Stuff
}
```

Please could someone explain the reason I still get a warning and the best practice way to deal with this?

Comment: At which line exactly? In general that means that you are trying to compare an `Object` with a `String`. Since not both are strings `Object.Equals` is used instead of `String.Equals`. That will just compare the references and not the values.

Comment: Sorry  , The Last 3 condition which i Try .  In the first Condition 1st line There  have showing error

Comment: Control   oControl ;           Object Type

Comment: I doubt that you still get this compiler warning with the current code. Try to rebuild your solution. Both are strings so the  [`String.Equals(String, String)`-method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hkt4325(v=vs.110).aspx) is used with [`==`-operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.op_equality(v=vs.110).aspx) and not `Object.Equals`.

Answer (score 0):

These options will work:

```
if (Equals(ocontrol.Name, oDataRowView["ConName"])) // likely best option

if ((string)ocontrol.Name == oDataRowView["ConName"].ToString()) // assuming neither item is null

if (ocontrol.Name as string == oDataRowView["ConName"] as string) // assuming second item is actually a string
```